# How to communicate between multiple discord Bots?

Tags: python, tcp, discord, aiohttp, pycord

I am trying to let two discord Bots communicate together.
Since I am using py-cord and aiohttp is already in my stack, I thought maby I could use aiohttp to to that.
I could not find a way to do that using the aiohttp websockets. I could not create a permanent tcp connection that I could use from both direction in case of an event.
One direction works fine.

Do you have an advice how I could let the Bots communicate?

How would you let the bots communicate?

(I am using Python)

At the moment my plan is to make a webserver listener on one bot and when the other needs something, it makes a request to the webserver.

EDIT:
Why Websockets? They are most efficient!

Comment: Just a suggestion: Let both bots run a webserver, then on events send the information between the two on their own endpoints. Another option is to let both bots run in the same script, but I assume you cannot do that here. I haven't read too much into py-cord, but if you are able to run a webserver on one server - why is a websocket a problem? Please provide more details on your code so I can take a look :)  Hope that helps in a way

Comment: You could try using pycord ipc for that.
On one of the bots create an ipc server and the other one has the client

Comment: link: https://pypi.org/project/pycord-ext-ipc/